# Use Batch file to rename files and increment postfix

Tags: batch-file, rename, increment

I have a list of files. Every day I generate a new list of files. I need to keep this list of files previously generated. I would like to add and number to the end of yesterday's file and I would like to increment all previous files by 1 so that yesterday's file is always 0001. For example:

Files generated yesterday are:

```
P.xls
T.xls
W.xls
```

I would like to run a batch file that names them:

```
P0001.xls
T0001.xls
W0001.xls
```

Ok. I can do that part. No big deal. The files are always named P, T, and W, so that part is easy. The harder part is to rename P0001.xls, T0001.xls, and W0001.xls every single day. I can make a batch file that starts like this:

```
rename P9998.xls P9999.xls
```

and work my way down to P0001.xls, but that is ridiculous. I don't want to type 10,000 lines for each file.

Any help on this batch file would be greatly appreciated.

Keith

Answer (score 0):

Rather than iterate all possible numbers, it is more efficient to process just the files that exist. I temporarily append `.ren` to the files as a first step so that I don't have to worry about processing in descending order.

This solution assumes that all existing .XLS files that begin with P W or T are to be renamed and follow the correct naming convention. It also assumes the files to be renamed are in the current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%C in (P T W) do ren %%C*.xls *.*.ren
ren ?.xls.ren ?0000.*
for %%F in (*.xls.ren) do (
  set "num=%%F"
  set /a "num=1!num:~1,4! - 9999"
  set "num=000!num!"
  ren %%F ?!num:~-4!.xls
)
```

Here is a more direct but perhaps less efficient version that safely ignores .XLS files beginning with P T or W that do not meet the naming convention. Here I sort the files in descending order so that I only need to rename each file once.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d /o-n *.xls^|findstr /rix [PTW][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].xls'
) do (
  set "num=%%F"
  set /a "num=1!num:~1,4! - 9999"
  set "num=000!num!"
  ren %%F ?!num:~-4!.xls
)
for %%C in (P T W) do ren %%C.xls ?0001.*
```

I am making use of some little known features of how REN handles wildcards. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for more information.

Comment: @KeithMungo - Don't forget to accept the answer if it fully answers your question. Simply click on the check mark near the upper left corner. That action lets others know the question has been answered, it awards you 2 reputation points, and awards the answer poster 15 points.

Comment: @MethodMan - Don't ask new questions as comments to existing answers. If you have a question, then post your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The Batch file below achieve the desired rename in a faster way because it process file numbers instead file names, so 3 files are renamed in each cycle; also, a `for /L` loop run faster than a regular `for` with file names. The speed is important if the number of files is large.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Rename files generated yesterday
ren ?.xls ?0000.xls

rem Get the number of the last file
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D /O-N *.xls') do (
   set lastName=%%a
   goto continue
)
:continue
set /A oldNumber=1%lastName:~1,4%, newNumber=oldNumber+1, numFiles=newNumber-10000

rem Rename all files
for /L %%a in (1,1,%numFiles%) do (
   ren ?!oldNumber:~1!.xls ?!newNumber:~1!.xls
   set /A oldNumber-=1, newNumber-=1
)
```